# laravel mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel

I have this statement in my search function

```
if(!empty($project) && !empty($type)){
            $result = Project::where('id', 'LIKE', "%{$project}%")->with(['type', function ($query) use ($type) {
                $query->where('id', 'like', $type);
            }])->get();
}
```

it returns

> mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

#### Logic

1. `$project` = `project.id`
2. `$type` = `type.id`
3. If `$project and $ type` **both have values** then **get project where id = $project**
4. Then eager load `type` to that project **where id = $type**

is like we say `types, where types.project_id = projects.id and where types.id = $type` but with eager load instead of query.

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because with() takes an associative array in order to constrain eager loads. try this

```
if(!empty($project) && !empty($type)){
            $result = Project::where('id', 'LIKE', "%{$project}%")->with(['type'=> function ($query) use ($type) {
                $query->where('id', 'like', $type);
            }])->get();
}
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to work. may i ask ? what if i add another eagers but still want to filter `type`? let say `->with(['scales', 'categories', 'type' => function(....` so i have all these eager models but i only user my filter on `type`? is that posibble?

Comment: @mafortis YES very possible

Comment: got it :) i just have to add my other eagers after this `type` closed `...}, 'scale'])->get();`